# Why does Option<NonZeroU32> not require using explicit Some?

Tags: rust, algebraic-data-types

I have noticed by accident that the following code compiles and works, but I am curious why?
I understand why Option of u32 requires an explicit Some, but I don't understand why NonZeroU32 is special and actually forbids from explicitly using Some.

```
use std::num::NonZeroU32;

fn main() {
    let x : Option<u32> = Some(1);
    //let y : Option<NonZeroU32> = Some(NonZeroU32::new(2)); //doesn't compile
    let y : Option<NonZeroU32> = NonZeroU32::new(2);
    println!("{} {}", x.unwrap(), y.unwrap());
}
```

I tried looking in https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/num/struct.NonZeroU32.html
and https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/num/nonzero.rs.html#25-155

I noticed that there is

```
#[rustc_nonnull_optimization_guaranteed]
```

and I think this is why explicit Some is not required, but I lack experience to confirm my theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`NonZeroU32::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/num/struct.NonZeroU32.html#method.new) return `None` if the argument `n` is zero. The `Option` is a failure indicator of the function. It's a very common pattern in Rust and have no relation to `rustc_nonnull_optimization_guaranteed`

Answer (score 11):

No, this is because [`NonZeroU32::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/num/struct.NonZeroU32.html#method.new) already returns `Option<NonZeroU32>` (it returns `None` if given zero).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have just found 
https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/num/nonzero.rs.html#65-72
but wasn't sure :)
I should have searched myself a bit more.